# Controls Repositioning issue when using SharedSizeGroup in ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have two item controls that are sharing the width using SharedSizeGroup.
Now the issue is whenever i am updating the text inside the textbox,say the setting the text in the second row to 999999999 & then deleting the text,controls are not repositioning themselves.

Here is my code :-

XAML :-

```
<Window x:Class="BindingGroupSample.Window2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindingGroupSample"
    Title="Window2" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:GroupNameGenerator x:Key="GroupNameGenerator1" />
    <local:GroupNameGenerator x:Key="GroupNameGenerator2" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
            <ItemsControl Name="ItemsControl1">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="{Binding Converter={StaticResource GroupNameGenerator1}}" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Index}" Background="Gray"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
            <ItemsControl Name="ItemsControl2">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="{Binding Converter={StaticResource GroupNameGenerator2}}" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace BindingGroupSample
{
public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<Temp> list1 = new ObservableCollection<Temp>();
    ObservableCollection<Temp> list2 = new ObservableCollection<Temp>();  

    public Window2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


         for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)    
         {
             list1.Add(new Temp() { Index = i });   
             list2.Add(new Temp() { Name = "AA" + i +i });      
         }  
        ItemsControl1.ItemsSource = list1;    
        ItemsControl2.ItemsSource = list2;        

    }
}


public class GroupNameGenerator : IValueConverter
{
    public Int32 Index { get; set; }
    public GroupNameGenerator()
    {
        Index = 0;
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return String.Format("Group{0}", ++Index);
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}


public class Temp
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
}
```

Please suggest something to achieve w/o taking any events to refresh the control items.

Actually I want to achieve my UI something like below:-

```
                Item 1     Item 2     Item3    Item 4
    Heading 1:    AA        AA1        AA2      AA3
    Heading 2:    20        10         11       89
    Heading 3:    10        11         89        7
    Heading 4:   Expand     Expand    Expand    Expand
```

Also there will be a horizontal scrollbar from Item 1 to Item 4 visible all the times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should go another way. Let's fill one list with all values and use UniformGrid in ItemTemplate.

C#:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
    list1.Add(new Temp()
    {
        Index = i,
        Name = "AA" + i + i
    });
}
ItemsControl3.ItemsSource = list1;
```

XAML:

```
<ItemsControl Name="ItemsControl3">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="2">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Index}" Background="Gray" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </UniformGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I hope that's what you needed!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply...This is what I needed but there is one more problem,I have used expander control so if I take uniform grid whenever I expand my expander,all the row heights got increased.Moreover I have one more item control at the left to give headings for each row.I bounded the height of left item control & right one with the SharedSizegroup..So If I use the uniform grid I cannot align them properly.Can you please provide some help for the same..

Comment: Replace UniformGrid with StackPanel to allow a different rows to have a different height. Of course it is unable to align ItemsControl at the left by using SharedSizeGroup. But have a look: row headers are simply like row values placed at the beginning. You can use AlternationIndex and AlternationCount in ItemTemplate's trigger to determine whether your cell is the first and if so render it as row header.

Comment: Thanks once again...But if I use the alteration index,then how i will allow my scrollbar to start from the second column as first will be my row header...Sorry for asking too many questions & disturbing u again n again..I have updated my question to add the look of my UI to explain it better...

Comment: You are right. I forgot about scroll bar. Is row count known at design time? Do you actually use ItemsControl for each row?

Comment: Yes I know the rowcount but Columns will be added at the runtime using ItemsControl...Number of columns will depend upon the number of items in the collection.Also I have seperate validation for each row.So without Items control I am not able to set validations.So using two diff items controls.one for left header & another for the content.

Comment: If you know the row count then you may bind height of each Heading to corresponding ItemsControl (according to its row).

Comment: Marking this one as answered and raising another question for my problem..Thanks Marat for guiding me.Really appreciate your help.